# Racket raw strings

Tags: regex, string, racket, rawstring

In Racket you have to escape backslashes in strings, therefore Windows paths and regexes become verbose.

> For example, the regular expression `(.*)\1` can be represented with the string `"(.*)\\1"` or the regexp constant `#rx"(.*)\\1"`; the \ in the regular expression must be escaped to include it in a string or regexp constant. [Source: [Regexp Syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html#%28part._regexp-syntax%29)]

In many languages like Perl and Ruby regexes are supported syntactically `/\([a-z]+\)/`, in others there are optional [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation), like in Python `r"\([a-z]+\)"`. It seems that Racket doesn't support raw strings, where you don't need to escape backslashes, natively. Is there any method to implement them, a third-party library, a proposal, whatever?

See also:

- [Regular Expressions @ The Racket Guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/regexp.html)
- [Regular Expressions @ The Racket Reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html)

Comment: Strings are part of the read syntax. Therefore, you can extend the reader (either by using a read macro, or a completely new reader) that will read raw strings, using whatever syntax you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Chris mentioned, a custom reader can do this.

An example of a reader that Racket already supplies, that you could use, is [`at-exp`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader-internals.html?#%28mod-path._at-exp%29):

```
#lang at-exp racket

@~a{C:\Windows\win.ini}
;; "C:\\Windows\\win.ini"

@~a{This is a string
    with newlines.}
;; "This is a\nstring with newlines."
```

I like to use [`~a`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7ea%29%29) with this because it converts anything to a string, and it's only two characters to type.

However for your regexp example, you can't use `~a` or `#rx`. Instead you should use `regexp`:

```
@regexp{(.*)\1}
;; #rx"(.*)\\1"
```

In all of these examples, `@function{string}` is read as `(function "string")` -- basically. There are some nuances you can read about in the documentation for `at-exp` and Scribble.